# unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder

Tags: android, sdk, build, jar, dx

i noticed in the "console" box of my Eclipse program, that it said "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\lib" , so it has 2 back slashes \platform-tools\lib, this was caused by incomplete installation on my part, so it cannot find the "dx.jar" so when i go to export and compile the project app i now get this error that unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!

i have tried deleting and reinstalling sdk tools from sdk manager, and i still have the same problem.
Please can anybody help

Answer (score 3):

Try to update SDK Manager with privilege mode. I had the same problem and was solve it updating the SDK tools and restarting Eclipse.